# ASP.NET Visitors counter

Tags: c#, asp.net, counter

I am creating a counter for my webpage. What wan't to achieve is that every time user visits my asp.net application, it stores his data into database. I am using Global.asax and event Application_Start. Here is my code .

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        WebpageCounter.SaveVisitor(new WebpageVisitor()
        {
            VisitorIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress,
            VisitedOn = DateTime.Now
        });
    }
```

But it never stores anything into database. The function SaveVisitor has been tested and it is functional.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Also see this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669049/implementing-a-visitor-counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application_Start is runs only when process created - not every visit.

You can use Application_BeginRequest instead.

Comment: So which event do I have to use ? Or where to place my code ?

Answer (score 4):

`Application_Start()` is only called once for the lifetime of the application domain - not for every request to your site. Also see ["ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Code for the code behind:

C#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.countMe();

        DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));

        lblCounter.Text = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString();
    }

    private void countMe()
    {
        DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));

        int hits = Int32.Parse(tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString());

        hits += 1;

        tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"] = hits.ToString();

        tmpDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));

    }
```

VB.NET

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.countMe()

        Dim tmpDs As New DataSet()
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"))

        lblCounter.Text = tmpDs.Tables(0).Rows(0)("hits").ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub countMe()
        Dim tmpDs As New DataSet()
        tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"))

        Dim hits As Integer = Int32.Parse(tmpDs.Tables(0).Rows(0)("hits").ToString())

        hits += 1

        tmpDs.Tables(0).Rows(0)("hits") = hits.ToString()

        tmpDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"))
    End Sub
```

XML file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<counter>
  <count>
     <hits>0</hits>
  </count>
```

Answer (score 1):

This information can be logged by IIS, and then queried/transformed using the excellent [logparser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274). You could also put Google Analytics on your site - its free version is sufficient for all but the busiest sites. If you still feel the need to do this yourself, then `Application_BeginRequest` is a better place to record this.

**EDIT**: You could implement it as a module, like [the MSDN Custom Module Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and then your app could be a little more modular

Comment: protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            WebpageCounter.SaveVisitor(new WebpageVisitor()
            {
                VisitorIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress,
                VisitedOn = DateTime.Now
            });
        }

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?